# Programmatically going from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I've set this button up programmatically and I've been trying to figure out how, when it is pressed to segue to another `ViewController`. I've been trying to look up the type of code I would need for that to happen. I can't seem to find any.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "Camera.png") as UIImage!
    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width / 2 - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 70, 70, 70)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is how I have it set-up could someone please either direct me to the right type of code I need to use or give me an example. Thank you

Comment: You need example of code how to jump from 1 VC to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add action to your button this way:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

After that add helper method:

```
func buttonTapAction(sender:UIButton!){

    //this code will navigate to next view when you press button.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Full code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named: "s.png") as UIImage!
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width / 2 - 30, self.view.frame.size.height - 70, 70, 70)
        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonTapAction(sender:UIButton!){

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=42249216628600669772) sample for more info.

Comment: Hi thank your this works, but I'm having a problem with the self.navigationController? becasue the way I set my button up is its overlaying on a tab view.

Comment: try this: `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Just one line

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewC‌​ontrollerWithIdentifier("view2") as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a manual segue from your ViewController to TargetViewController.

Now, add an action to the button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

In the action do this.

```
func buttonAction(sender:AnyObject)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("manualSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

first create an action for button like this..

```
- (IBAction)btnInvite:(id)sender {

}
```

then import viewcontroller where you want to move on like...

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
```

and finally put below code in to your button action method whatever we create in above

```
- (IBAction)btnInvite:(id)sender {
YourViewController *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController Identifier Name"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];}
```

hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"yourViewController") as! yourViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated:true)
```

Only change yourViewController with your Viewcontroller name

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to allow future users to better understand what your code does.